# Access Azure Blob Files also by Azure Public IPs

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-public-ip

I would like to access a blob e.g. https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/container/file.dat also by using a public IP from Azure in my embedded application. For example https://1.2.3.4/container/file.dat should be the same file.

I have checked Azure Load Balancer, App Gateway, App Proxy, Azure CDN and Azure Front Door services bud could not find a solution.

EDIT:

Azure storage has private link option. I tried today and no success. Basically I am trying to link my public IP to Azure storage blob access.

Answer (score 0):

This is the error you get:

[image]

First, make sure your blob can be access by public:

[image]

And if you don't have requirement to set networking, please make sure:

[image]

Then set the container access level:

[image]

[image]

Then, it should be no problem.

Comment: Thank you very much @Bowman Zhu for this clear explanation. Public access is enabled and I can already access the file with the domain name. The problem is that I need to replace domainname mystorage.blob.core.windows.net with a public IP. Also tried Azure private link today and it did not worked.